# CALCULATE and COUNTROWS returns only 1 - PowerBI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to count the number of rows in a subset based on two filters. The filters work, but insted of returning the total number of of rown in my subset, I just get a 1 for every row in the subset.

I need it to return the number of rows in the subset (e.g. 200). I am currently getting a column of 1s.

It works fine without CALCULATE and filters.

```
Colunm = CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( TABLE ) ;

    /* FILTER 1 */
    TABLE[TEXT_FIELD] = "TEXT";  

    /* FILTER 2 */
    DATESBETWEEN ( TABLE[DATE]; 
        (MAX ( TABLE[DATE] ) - 30);
        MAX ( TABLE[DATE] )
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because your measure is being evaluated within its local filter context.

Try adding `ALL(TABLE)` as another filter to remove that filter context.